# Why is India purchasing S-400 rather than the US made missiles?

Tags: united-states, india, military, weapons

Purchasing Russian missiles have risks of inviting US sanctions.

Since [India is officially a US ally](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/54798/32479), Why is India purchasing S-400 rather than the US-made missiles (Patriot or David's Sling or THAAD)?

If tech-transfer was the issue, S-400 doesn't come with a tech-transfer. Patriot and THAAD may also deny tech-transfer. In that case, Israel's David's Sling might have been a better option.

---

**P.S.** My personal opinion is, India was probably trying to (1) avoid lengthy negotiation, (2) engage Russia with defense deals so that they don't lean or sell arms to Pakistan.

Comment: India is not in NATO and uses a lot more Soviet or newer Russian equipment. The US may or may not want or afford to sanction a larger country located elsewhere, i.e. closer to China. [Supposedly](https://english.alarabiya.net/en/News/gulf/2017/10/05/Saudi-Arabia-agrees-deal-for-Russian-S400-missile-defense-systems) even the Saudis are making a deal on the S-400.

Comment: It seems the US has filp-flopped or was unsure whether to sanction India or not for that. https://foreignpolicy.com/2018/08/29/washington-warns-of-sanctioning-india-over-russian-missile-system/ Or more accurately said, there were conflicting views on that in the US circles of power. Calculations may again be different under a new US administration, etc.

Comment: A wild guess: they're cheaper or better.

Comment: @user253751, so, what is the problem with Turkey buying a 'better and cheaper' missile and India is not?

Comment: also, during the 70s/80s India was allied with Russia, while the US was allied with Pakistan. certain things have a long tail.

Comment: "Since India is officially a US ally" [citation requested]

Comment: @MartinSchröder, https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/54798/32479

Comment: @user366312 politics.  Its something to hit Turkey with at a time when relationship is already at a low.

Comment: India is in the process of acquiring the National Advanced Surface to Air Missile System-II (NASAMS-II) from the US. 
https://www.businesstoday.in/current/economy-politics/india-to-buy-us-missile-system-to-create-multi-layered-aerial-shield-for-delhi/story/354773.html

Comment: India is more interested in technology transfer than 
 merely  weapon transfer. Maybe  in hope that Russia will aid India in developing it's own missile defence systems or components like radar etc. in future and US is not in favor of technology transfer to other nations because of fear of getting it in wrong hands.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, a false assumption. S-400 doesn't come with a tech-transfer, Israel's David's Sling does.

Comment: BTW for your point no. 1 ,  the below webpage says   negotiations were going on with Russia from long time as told by Defence Minister Nirmala Sitharaman.

https://m.businesstoday.in/story/india-russian-signs-dollar-5-billion-deal-5-s400-missile-systems/1/283970.html

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, the news link is from 2018. India has already placed an order without the tech-transfer agreement. India can at best ask for local assembly, not full tech-transfer, as S-400 is Russia's pinnacle of SAM/ADS system. They will not sell this tech so easily.

Comment: Yeah you are right.  I was not specifically talking about tech transfer of S400 , but in hope that with this deal Russia will aid India in  other defence technology  areas like guns , tanks , light aircraft  etc. or a jet engine may be. Also in the area of space exploration like  designing cryogenic engines. Not a political or defence expert though and all these are my wild guesses.

Comment: *but in hope that with this deal Russia will aid India in other defense technology areas like guns, tanks, light aircraft, etc. or a jet engine may be. Also in the area of space exploration like designing cryogenic engines.* --- wrong again. India's DRDO has already been working on these projects for at least 3 decades. If they had to seek Russian help, that would have been sought long ago. *and all these are my wild guesses.* --- kindly stop guessing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117491/discussion-between-swiftpushkar-and-user366312).